# How to display a compiler warning when the following IEnumerable methods chain is used?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, compiler-warnings, stylecop

I have the following repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
      List<T> GetDataList();

      T FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

Most of the time `GetDataList()` is used. However for performance reasons, there is a method `FirstOrDefault()` which is an optimised version and take advantage there is only a single domain data object that will be returned .

The idea is to avoid this :

```
MyRepo.GetDataList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.SomeField == ...) //many deep copy
```

And use this instead :

```
MyRepo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SomeField == ...) //single deep copy
```

However some developers use the first technique (which is non optimal) because they are not aware of the repository `FirstOrDefault()` method.

Is there a way to create a custom warning / validation rule ? Using style cop is allowed. It would throw a warning every time the following chain is used :

```
GetDataList(). (...) .FirstOrDefault()
//warning: use Repository.FirstOrDefault() instead
```

Comment: Can't you make `IEnumerable<T> GetData()` and then other developers will "optimize" it themselves?

Comment: Why is `GetDataList` not able to return an `IQueryable<T>` instead, so that developers can make use of their existing LINQ experience rather than you slapping their hands each time that they do?

Comment: @Sinatr you need to make it `IQueryable` then, otherwise the same problem will occur.

Comment: @Evk, agreed if it's a query (e.g. database).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : while look like a good idea (and it provide more flexibility that using custom repository methods) I want to avoid changing the return type of that method which is used is lot of projects. There is probably thousands of calls to fix and to check (`IQueryable<T>` != `List<T>`).

Comment: (I promise I won't keep badgering you after this :-)) - but if you're in the mood to write something to analyse code and highlight misuse, wouldn't you be able to write something that finds those call-sites?

Comment: @tigrou, warning is a workaround to the problem which is caused by a wrong design. Simple: either change design (to avoid problems) or live with possibility, what someone may ignore your *recommendations*. You can create documentation and make sure everybody will read to know about optimized method. Or you can make a new `IQueryable<T> GetData()` method and mark previous as `[Obsolete]`, this way you don't break anything and eventually everybody will switch to a new method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I agree with comments and this is probably bad design, BUT I *think* you could do this:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    [Obsolete("don't do this")]
    public T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        //could call underlying method;  calling this will return null/0/etc
        return default(T);
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    MyList<T> GetDataList();
    T FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

The following code then has effects described in the comments:

```
var tmp = new MyList<int>();
//this gives compiler warning & green underline in visual studio:
var xxx = tmp.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 0);  

//this doesn't give compiler warning as you're calling the underlying method
var yyy = (tmp as List<int>).FirstOrDefault(x => x == 0);
```

Comment: It should be the other way around. `FirstOrDefault()` is not the issue, it's `GetDataList()`.

Comment: The way I read is is that they wanted the `FirstOrDefault()` call _on the **result** of `GetDataList()`_ to return a warning.  My example code isn't using the repository - just showing how `MyList<T>` behaves like `List<T>` except if you try to use `FirstOrDefault()` on it... so by replacing the `List<T>` with that you can achieve the desired effect.  I certainly agree it is a code smell though...